How can I update hiddenDays when I modify events
When I update events I want to update hiddenDays to not show days that do not have events. I'm using it in vue 3, try this code:
const calendarApi = await calendarRef.value?.getApi();
if (calendarApi) {
     calendarApi.setOption('hiddenDays', hiddenDays);
}

But that means that you cannot scroll later and the component does not look good. How can I do?
